# IONIC - BluetoothSerial in constructor makes all elements invisible

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, bluetooth

My ultimate goal is to build an app that would have a button, which when pressed:

1. LIST all unpaired Bluetooth devices -----(Arduino HC-06 in particular)
2. Select a device to CONNECT to
3. WRITE data to the device

To begin, I was testing the button functionality.

**My button is visible and shows an alert after pressing it:**

**HTML:**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      About
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <button ion-button  ng-click="showAlert()">FIND</button>
</ion-content>
```

**JS:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-about',
  templateUrl: 'about.html'
})

export class AboutPage {

  constructor(public alertCtrl:AlertController) {

  }

  showAlert() {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'TEST TITLE',
      subTitle: 'TEST SUBTITLE',
      buttons: ['OK']
    });
    alert.present();
  }
```

**Now to use Bluetooth, I need to include BluetoothSerial in constructor, however, the button disappears after including it:**

**JS:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { BluetoothSerial } from '@ionic-native/bluetooth-serial';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-about',
  templateUrl: 'about.html'
})

export class AboutPage {

  constructor(public alertCtrl:AlertController,
              public bluetoothSerial: BluetoothSerial) {

  }

  showAlert() {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'TITLE HERE',
      subTitle: 'RANDOM',
      buttons: ['OK']
    });
    alert.present();
  }
```

I was testing all this on an Android device.

**QUESTION 1:** How do I fix this?

**QUESTION 2:** Maybe somebody has done this whole app, and could share their code?

Comment: When u say the button disappears, you mean this button? `<button ion-button  ng-click="showAlert()">FIND</button>`. By the way, you should do `(click) ="showAlert()` instead.

Comment: yes, this button.
I changed to `(click) ="showAlert()"`, still the error occurs.

Comment: Yeah that was just a best practice, didn't expect it to fix anything. Anyway, Let's do the standard `ionic platform remove android && ionic platform add android` and see if updating the platform does anything.

Comment: Also try launching it on device with `ionic run android -c` and make sure there are no runtime javascript errors that block rendering before it begins.

Comment: I used `ionic cordova platform remove android` & `ionic cordova platform add android`    ------>   no luck.

`ionic run android -c`    ------->    no luck.

Comment: Divide and conquer. Reduce your code as much as possible keeping just `constructor(public bluetoothSerial: BluetoothSerial) { console.log('sup!'); }`

Comment: removed `alertCtrl`, left only `bluetoothSerial` as you said -------> no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED

Had to add BluetoothSerial to my App's Module (`src/app/app.module.ts`).
http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/#Add_Plugins_to_Your_App_Module